# Which Design Pattern best suits for this scenario in an MVC built application?

Tags: php, design-patterns, model-view-controller

Lets say we have an application where people can create characters, similar to World of Warcraft or Everquest. We have chosen to use MVC.

We need to show a list of characters to the user from their homepage after they login to the application. Initially the only business requirement to show the user their list of characters was to retrieve a list of all active characters associated to the user account.
This list of Characters also needs to be accessible across multiple controllers.

At some point, the business model changes and a payment status is put in place to only allow the user to view certain characters based on the user's payment status. For example, payment status of Gold level allows you to access all characters, silver limits to 2 types of characters, etc, etc.

```
    <?php
    class Controller{
        public function index(){
            //array of users active characters(would be done via lookups with datamapper pattern)
            $arrCharacters = array(0=>$objChar1, 1=>$objChar2);

            //set a payment status of silver(would be done via lookups with datamapper pattern)
            $objPayment = new objPayment();
            $objPayment->setStatus('Silver');

            //loop through each character object and check the character access level against what the user paid for
            //if the character access level is not at least equal to the payment level, remove the character object from the
            //array that we want to pass to the output(view)
            foreach($arrCharacters as $key=>$objCharacter){                
                if($objCharacter->getCharAccessLevel()<=$objPaymentLevel()){
                    unset($arrCharacters[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Obviously this approach will work, but it would mean I would have to copy that functionality into every controller I need to access the characters for the user from. Any suggestions on a more efficient way to solve this problem. I cannot see a good design pattern that would suit my case.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a MVC problem but it can be easily tackled with interfaces.

For instance you could create an `PlayerService` interface and create different implementations. In this case a *free* and *payed* implementation.

```
interface PlayerService {
    public function getPlayers();
}

class FreePlayerService implements PlayerService {
    public function getPlayers() { ... }
}

class PayedPlayerService implements PlayerService {
    private $status;

    public function __construct($status) { ... }
    public function getPlayers() { /* return players based on status */ }
}
```

Controller

```
class PlayerController {
    PlayerService $service;

    public function setPlayerService(PlayerService $service) {
        $this->service = $service;
    }

    public function index() {
        $players = $service->getPlayers();
    }
}
```

Now you can set the controller service to either one of the implementations and it wouldn't know the difference.